# C3 Stacked chart loaded from CSV with dynamic categories

Tags: javascript, csv, c3.js

I'm trying to draw a stacked (area) line chart using C3.

My code, as it stands, allows me to create a line chart without stacking :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    x: 'x',
    url: 'GeneratedData.csv',
    type: 'area',
    /* groups: [  ['data1', 'data2'] ] */
    },
    axis : {
        x : {
            type : 'timeseries',
            tick : {
              format : "%y-%m-%d" 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is that the data is generated in such a way that I do not know the name of the columns in advance, so I cannot set their type or group them 
(hence the comments around `groups: [  ['data1', 'data2'] ]`)

My CSV looks something like this :

x,LT62Ag,5NwafDw,Pac0dA
2017-01-22,85797,145417,626803
2017-01-23,71837,105246,440776
2017-01-24,77650,108834,442359
...
2017-03-31,87359,102618,467113

How should I proceed to create the groups from the dynamic data to stack the charts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this to your chart declaration, it'll pull out the names of the data series (apart from x) and turn them into one big group:

```
onrendered: function () {
    var seriesNames = this.data.targets.map (function (d) {
      return d.id;
    }).filter (function (sname) {
        return sname !== "x";
    });
    this.api.groups ([seriesNames]);
  },
```

Ideally it should be done with the 'oninit' declaration rather than the groups reset on every rendering, but there seems to be some sort of bug that makes the bars go 1 pixel wide when you do that...

I guess a flag that decides whether the groups have already been set could be employed though...

https://jsfiddle.net/1bb60dd9/